# How can I make this query in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have a list of paths in a database.

```
\\apollon\HardDev\01_Elektronik\***
\\apollon\Sales\Kunden\S\***
\\apollon\HardDev\02_Optik\Optik\***_Projekte_Salb\***
\\apollon\Sales\Kunden\O\***\Auftrag 2002_2008-09-09
\\apollon\Sales\Kunden\H\***\Auftrag 4534_2013-07-26
\\apollon\User\***\quickies_2016\BSI_screenshots\Neuer Ordner
\\apollon\Sales\Kunden\G\***\Auftrag 2153_2009-06-24
\\apollon\HardDev\01_Elektronik\***\bestuecker_afem_v12
\\apollon\User\***\quickies_2015\src_***
\\apollon\Sales\Kunden\H\***\4352IO_2013-06-07
etc.
```

Now I needed a query that gets a path as a parameter and only returns to me the direct subfolder and whether there are subfolders in which.

**EXAMPLE:**

Function gets the path

```
\\apollon\User\Walzenbach
```

and as result I would like to know that the path has the following subfolders

```
{dir = "\\apollon\User\Walzenbach\docs", subfolderCount = 2}
{dir = "\\apollon\User\Walzenbach\doku", subfolderCount = 0}
{dir = "\\apollon\User\Walzenbach\backup", subfolderCount = 10}
```

That means the folder docs has 2 subfolders, the folder doku has no subfolders and backup has 10 subfolders.

The SQL would go in that direction. But I am also not sure if this is the best SQL query for it and I also need it in Linq

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you tried something and have problem with it?

Comment: I have tried it with Linqer but it always reports error that the SQL can not be translated

Comment: This question in its current state is too broad. What have you tried? How is the result different from what you expect? Please read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and see what is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: can't you use StartsWith function that is translated to LIKE 'expression%' ? for example from d in directories where d.path.StartsWith(path) select d

Comment: I have already done that (I think) the bigger problem is the number of subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion :

```
var query=from d in directories
          join sf in directories on d.Path equals sf.ParentPath into grp1
          from sf in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
          let result=new {dir=d,sub=sf}
          where reault.dir.Path.StartsWith(path)
          group result by result.dir.Path into grp2
          select new {dir=grp2.Key,subFolderCount=grp2.Count()};
```

Comment: I'll will test it

Comment: Oh!  there's a problem here. we should use left join instead of join in order to get folders that they don't have any sub folder.

Comment: It works so far except for the empty folder as you said. Have also ever searched google but Linq seems the leftjoin not so easy to work

Comment: I have changed the query so that it uses left join.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
string directoryName = "\\apollon\User\Walzenbach"
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
// TODO: exception if !directory.Exists;

var result = directory.EnumerateDirectories()
    .Select(subDirectory => new
    {
        SubDirectory = subDirectory,       // This is a DirectoryInfo

        // if you prefer the name, instead of the Directory:
        SubDirectoryName = subDirectory.Name,

        // count the number of subfolders of this subfolder:
        SubFolderCount = subFolder.EnumerateDirectories().Count(),
    });
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: I can not access via DirectoryInfo because the data comes from a MSSQL database, not from a live FileSystem ...

Comment: Is have that in my question "I have a list of paths in a database."

Answer (score 0):

So now I have a SQL that at least reasonably does what I want ... But Linqer can not translate it into Linq

```
SELECT [Directory], subfolderCount = 
    (SELECT COUNT([Directory])
    FROM [ArgesPerm].[argarm].[dirs]
    WHERE lower([Directory]) LIKE '\\apollon\user\walzenbach\%'
    GROUP BY [Directory])
FROM [ArgesPerm].[argarm].[dirs]
WHERE lower([Directory]) LIKE '\\apollon\user\walzenbach\%'
AND LEN(SUBSTRING([Directory], 3, 10000)) - Len(Replace(SUBSTRING([Directory], 3, 10000), '\', '')) < 3
GROUP BY [Directory]
ORDER BY [Directory]
```

Comment: SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Function "subfolderCount =" conversion is not supported.